# Java - Get data from JRMapCollectionDataSource

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm new into the forum.

I want to take this opportunity to thank everyone for the support you have given me many time.

My problem is the following:
I'm trying to get data from a JRMapCollectionDataSource from a java class.

Let me explain better...

I want to test the resulting PDF file from a batch operation.
I can access to the first level fields of the report (made with iReport), but not with the datasource of the internal TABLE represented into the PDF and populated with a JRMapCollectionDatasource.

My question is:
HOW can i access to a JRMapCollectionDatasource from java???

Thanks to all

Comment: Your question is unclear. How did you initiate the *JRMapCollectionDatasource*?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.When will I answer myself, I will give a complete answer to my own question.
In about six hours